# Get multiples of 10 and add the number

Tags: python

Guys i want to round the given numbers to the nearest multiple of 10. e.g. 15 should be rounded to 20 whereas 14 should be rounded to 10. After rounding the numbers, i want to find their sum.

Sample input is like (a list):
`[2, 18, 10]`

Sample output:
30

Sample 2:

`[10, 20, 1, 1]`

Output :
30

Comment: Can you post your attempt so far

Answer (score -1):

Using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [1,10,20,1]
np.around(numbers, decimals=-1).sum()
```

gives 30.